# ampersand in web adress

Tags: 14.04, system

Using Ubuntu 14.04, if I want to run for example: `system("firefox http://example.com/123&456")`, firefox only opens http://example.com/123. How can I get it to open the full address?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved: in order for the termninal to not break, you have to escape the ampersand by putting the **web address** in **single quotes**: `system("firefox 'http://example.com/123&456'")`

The same goes for direct terminal commands: `alexander@myUbuntu:~$ firefox 'http://example.com/123&456'`

Answer (score 1):

As per the [URI syntax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_resource_identifier#Generic_syntax), a web address cannot contain an ampersand. An ampersand does, however, signify the start of a query. Therefore, Firefox will try to retrieve the resource called `123` with the query `456`.

Answer (score 0):

The ampersand is used to separate commands in batch. You can escape it using `\` in front of the command, which would result in `system("firefox http://example.com/123\&456")`.

Hope that helps

Comment: I did not notice the adress was not in quotes, that is the problem. The whole adress should be quoted also.